# Why does smartmatch against keys %h fail and give an "Argument isn't numeric" warning?

Tags: perl, hash, smartmatch

In the following code, why does the first smartmatch fail to match and give the warning `Argument "two" isn't numeric in smart match`, while the second smartmatch works as expected (it matches)?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %h = ("one" => "un", "two" => "deux");
my $v = "two";
my @keys_h = keys %h;

say "matches first form"  if $v ~~ keys %h; # warning, doesn't match
say "matches second form" if $v ~~ @keys_h; # no warning, matches
```

I realize I could just use

```
$v ~~ %h
```

but I'd like to know why the first smartmatch doesn't work as I expect it to. I'm using Perl 5.10.1.

Comment: Never, ever, ever again post a partial error message when asking a question. Always post the entire error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because an array and a list are not the same thing.

```
$v ~~ @keys_h
```

is matching a scalar against an array, (`Any` vs `Array` in the [smart match behavior chart](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/pod/perlop.pod#Smartmatch_Operator)) returning true if the scalar matches an element of the array.

```
$v ~~ keys %h
```

is matching a scalar against a list. There is no rule for matching against a list, so the list is evaluated in scalar context, like

```
$v ~~ scalar(keys %h)
```

which resolves to

```
"two" ~~ 2
```

which is now a numeric comparison (`Any` vs. `Num`), which triggers the warning.

```
$v ~~ [ keys %h ]
```

would do what you want it to do, too.