# Perl: Similar conditions in an if. How to make it shorter & nicer?

Tags: perl

This is too long:

```
 if (    $self->{status} == 1 ||
         $self->{status} == 2 || 
         $self->{status} == 3
    ){                                                                                                                                                                                   
     $self->status(4);
 } else {                   
     croak "only 1,2 and 3 change to 4";
}
```

How would you make it nicer & shorter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe with the smart match operator:

```
if ( $self->{status} ~~ [1,2,3] ) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by "or"? This checks if status is 1 *or* 2 *or* 3 (cannot be all at once, can it)?

Comment: Unfortunately smartmatch was marked as experimental in perl 5.18.0. It may even go away in later perl versions. See the [perldelta](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.1/pod/perl5180delta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental) entry.

Comment: @SlavenRezic After introducing implicit smartmatch in Perl 5.12 w/ all that fanfare, it's now _experimental_?

Comment: @DavidW: Actually it was introduced in 5.10.0. And other things added in 5.10 will go: CPANPLUS is already marked as deprecated and will be removed in the next major release, Module::Build is the next deprecation candidate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ternary operator:

```
$self->{status} ~~ [1,2,3] ? $self->status(4) : croak "only 1,2 and 3 change to 4";
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's nicer, but..

```
foreach my $x (1,2,3,4,5){

    if (map{ $x == $_ ? 1 : () }(1,2,3) ){
        print "is 1,2, or 3\n";
    } else {
        printf "is %s\n", $x;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a mis-use of map, you'd be better off using `grep` instead, e.g. `if (grep { $x == $_ } (1,2,3))`.  It's still not an approach I'd use though.

Comment: very true. on both counts. I've been working in Python for too long.. 8)

Answer (score 1):

If status is always an positive integer You may:

```
if($self->{status} < 4)
{
   $self->status(4);
} else {                   
 croak "only 1,2 and 3 change to 4";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your perl is new enough to have smart match:

```
$self->{status} ~~ (1,2,3) and $self->status(4) or croak "...";
```

Comment: Careful -- [a list is not an array as far as smart match is concerned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243584/smartmatch-in-keys-of-string-hash/18243764#18243764).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way in the world, but doesn't rely on experimental features or loops:

```
if($self->{'status'} =~ m/^(1|2|3)$/) { ... }
```